# How do I run Docker within an Ec2 Instance using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, terraform

I was wondering if it was possible to install and run a Docker Container within an Ec2 instance via Terraform apply.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to run a simple Python Flask App inside a Docker container thats inside an Ec2 Instance. I need to perform some commands to get the ec2 instance downloading Docker and to pull and run the image from dockerhub

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Terraform resource called aws_instance to create the EC2 instance. To configure the EC2 instance you can use the user_data argument with the aws_instance resource, to run the commands to configure the EC2 instance and install docker.